# The generation has been cancelled because errors have been found by the check model

Tags: powerdesigner

I use PowerDesigner 15.2.

> The generation has been cancelled because errors have been found by the check model.

Why is it happened when I try to generate table in reflexive mandatory CDM to PDM?

Comment: Are the check errors in the Result List (Check Model tab), or the Output window (Check Model tab) related to this reflexive mandatory relationship?

Comment: It looks like this check status default was changed from Error to Warning in more recent versions. You can just launch the Check Model in the Conceptual Model to change the level of this check to Warning if you want.

Comment: It shows up on the alert tab when I checked "Dependent" on the Relationship Properties in the Conceptual Model. But when I unchecked the "Dependent", there is no error happened in the Check model tab when I generate table to Physical Model.

Is there any requirement in Conceptual Model to make the right reflexive mandatory for a table in a database?